# getJSON remote request without JSONP - Server

Tags: json, cross-domain, jsonp, getjson, same-origin-policy

I am trying to call JSON-data from a remote Server, but the server doesnt return valid JSONP formed data, only valid JSON data. ( confirmed with validators )

If i make the getJSON request( with &callback=? ), i get the valid JSON returned, but it doesnt trigger the callback function because it isnt valid JSONP.

Is there any good way to get access to the JSON data that was returned?

Comment: Are you in control of the remote server? Are you not able to call the remote server via your server script?

Comment: If you can also please mention the url of the remote server

Comment: i am note sure if i am allowed to mention it, so i better dont. And I also have no access to the server, only to the JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it has to be JSONP data because of how the whole thing works, it's basically including a JavaScript file by creating a `<script>` tag...and that response has to be valid JavaScript, an object literal (by itself) isn't valid JavaScript.

Think of it another way: if we *could* get JSON from a remote server, why would JSONP exist? :)

Comment: well if it doesnt work like that i may have to use php to get the JSON data and have php pass it to js. Wanted to avoid it, but seems this is the only way in this case.

Comment: @Tim - yup, a proxy is the only other alternative if they don't support JSONP do check that they don't use a different format to specify the callback though, some use `jsonpcallback=` or `jsoncallback=` or a completely different URL format.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, it sucks. I'm having the same issue with the Viddler API (browser side). It's sending JSON data back, but not in scripted JSON-P interface.

Thus, you have two options:

1. As people have said, use a back-end proxy to make requests server side.
2. If you only need to support one browser (Chromium in my case), use something like "*chromium-browser --disable-web-security*" to disable the "same-origin-policy" rule. This will allow you to make cross-domain requests, but only for this very specific situation.

Good luck man!

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all if your server your getting the JSON from doesn't support JSONP then your going to have to use a proxy.  If it does support JSONP you should format your request a little like the sample below. When you don't specify a callback in the $.getJSON(...&callback=?) then your request looks like this:

```
http://someurl?callback=123489234982
```

with some ridiculous number on the end of it and it makes your life a pain. So, you should specify a callback and format your code like the following:

```
<script>
     $.getJSON("your url?callback=callbackName", ....);

     function callbackName { do what you want with the json in here }
</script>
```

if that doesn't work then your server doesn't support JSONP :( here is a link to a php proxy you could use that is pretty good and has lots of documentation.

http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/